# laptop trackpad won't work after sleep

Tags: terminal, apt, touchpad

When I close my laptop lid and wait for it to sleep, the track pad won't work when I open it back up. I have no clue where to start with this.Please help.
It is an old gateway with linux mint 18.2

Answer (score 0):

Does your laptop have a synaptics touchpad (try running synclient -l) before a sleep event to see if the client responds.

When your touchpad fails to work, can you try the following please as root:

```
modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse
```

Comment: synclient -l does not work after sleep but it does before

Comment: no response from  modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse

Comment: also I was rooted

Comment: Since synclient worked before and not after, I think you'll need to unload the mouse/touchpad module after sleep followed by a reload. I am not able to tell you which module your kernel has loaded for the mouse, but sometimes you can find it easily with lsmod | grep -i mouse.